# SVG Fill Animation doesn't work on Firefox and Edge

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have a simple animation where an SVG fills on mouse over. It is working fine on Chrome, but I've found that it's doesn't workg on Firefox or Edge. I've tried few different approaches, but nothing seems to help. I'm new to SVG and I guess I'm missing something? What is the proper way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Here is the code:

```css
svg#bogeLogo {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

svg#bogeLogo #bogePath {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 8;
}

svg#bogeLogo #bogeFinal {
  fill: blue;
}

svg#bogeLogo #bogeClip rect {
  transition: all 1.4s ease-out !important;
  width: 0;
}

svg#bogeLogo:hover #bogeClip rect {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bogeLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2551.2 2551.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <path id="bogePath" d="M1263.5,1239.5l0-1l0.8-1194.9l-60.3,0l-0.6,1195.9l-1146.6,0.2v60.3l1146.6-0.5v1195h59l1-1195  l1231.9,0.5l0-60.3L1263.5,1239.5z M779.6,1037c98.3-37.9,134.5-130.5,138.1-140c6.8-18.3,31.3-87,1.9-161.1  c-20.6-52-58.4-82.8-74.8-95.9c-23.2-18.5-45.4-27.8-61.3-34.5c13.2-6.5,52.6-26.9,76.7-90.2c26-68.5-0.8-128.3-7.7-143.8  c-25.5-57.3-74.1-84.5-95-96.9c-31.8-19-83.7-25.5-104.2-26.3L410.2,248v3.2l-1.1,800.3v1.1l293.7-0.2  C721.3,1051.7,748.9,1048.8,779.6,1037z M570.6,394.5c46.8-9.2,80.5-1.6,97.8,3.8c19.2,6.1,27.6,12.5,32.6,17.3  c22.3,21.1,22.8,51.6,23,61.4c0.2,9.5,0.7,37.9-19.2,61.4c-18.5,21.9-43.5,28.8-65.2,30.7c-31.6,2.7-51.9,2.2-69-1.9V394.5z   M570.6,908.5V701.4c33.3-3.2,60.9-2.9,80.5-1.9c39.3,2,59.3,3.2,80.5,15.3c7,4,29.8,17.4,44.1,46c5.2,10.5,15.6,35.6,9.6,67.1  c-2.2,11.7-9.7,39.6-34.5,59.5c-11,8.7-25.4,16-63.3,21.1C660.3,912.2,620.2,914.9,570.6,908.5z M1835.5,1052.5  c218.7,0,395-184.3,395-403s-177.3-407-396-407s-396,188.3-396,407S1616.8,1052.5,1835.5,1052.5z M1835,390.5  c131.3,0,237.8,116.2,237.8,259.5S1966.3,909.5,1835,909.5S1597.2,793.3,1597.2,650S1703.7,390.5,1835,390.5z M636.5,1879.5v1l1,129  v0.1c73,0.1,142.9,0.3,216,0.4c-5.4,14.1-15,34.1-31.6,54.7c-5.9,7.2-35.7,43.1-89.4,63.7c-58.3,22.4-109.4,13.3-136.9,8.1  c-54.1-10.3-90.3-33.6-98.9-39.3c-39-25.9-60.5-55.8-71.8-71.8c-14.1-20-35.1-50.4-44.7-96.2c-2.4-11.6-10.4-54.2,2.7-107.1  c3.5-14.3,14.4-52.5,44.7-92.2c9.3-12.2,39.6-49.6,93.5-75.9c15.2-7.4,47.4-21.4,90.8-25.7c7.7-0.8,40-3.7,81.3,4.1  c19.2,3.6,46.7,9,77.2,25.7c14.7,8,31,19.8,63.7,43.4c8.8,6.3,15.7,12.5,20.5,16l90-106c-15.9-18.7-35.7-40.2-71-63  c-54-35-103.7-45.6-141.8-53.3c-31.3-6.3-86.6-17-158.1-6.3c-59.3,8.9-105.3,28.7-134.6,44.3c-49.5,26.2-82,56.1-95.8,69.6  c-39.5,38.6-60.6,75.2-65,83.1c-4.7,8.2-27.1,48.6-39.8,107.5c-2.3,10.9-9.1,44.7-9,89.4c0,22.3,0.4,59.9,13.6,106.6  c10.1,35.8,23.2,61,32.5,78.6c11,20.9,29,54.4,62.3,90.3c39,42.1,79.9,66.8,106.6,80.4c46.4,23.6,85.8,31.6,109.3,36.1  c25.3,4.9,72.3,11.8,131,6.3c27.9-2.6,61.2-6,102.1-21.7c14.8-5.7,58.3-23.6,103-63.2c42.8-37.9,65.1-76.5,79.5-102.1  c12.4-21.9,31.2-55.8,42.5-104.8c10.8-46.8,9.9-87,7.3-113.9L636.5,1879.5z M1019,1874.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9l1.4,0L1019,1874.6z   M1753.3,1919.6l291.8,1.1v-1.1l-1.1-142.2l-285.5,1.1h-1.1l1-137.9h1l304.6-3.3h1.1v-151.7h-464.6v2.1l-0.5,794l0,0.4h470.4v-146.4  h-317.1V1919.6z"/>
    <clipPath id="bogeClip">
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#bogePath"/>
  <path id="bogeFinal" clip-path="url(#bogeClip)" d="M1263.5,1239.5l0-1l0.8-1194.9l-60.3,0l-0.6,1195.9l-1146.6,0.2v60.3l1146.6-0.5v1195h59l1-1195  l1231.9,0.5l0-60.3L1263.5,1239.5z M779.6,1037c98.3-37.9,134.5-130.5,138.1-140c6.8-18.3,31.3-87,1.9-161.1  c-20.6-52-58.4-82.8-74.8-95.9c-23.2-18.5-45.4-27.8-61.3-34.5c13.2-6.5,52.6-26.9,76.7-90.2c26-68.5-0.8-128.3-7.7-143.8  c-25.5-57.3-74.1-84.5-95-96.9c-31.8-19-83.7-25.5-104.2-26.3L410.2,248v3.2l-1.1,800.3v1.1l293.7-0.2  C721.3,1051.7,748.9,1048.8,779.6,1037z M570.6,394.5c46.8-9.2,80.5-1.6,97.8,3.8c19.2,6.1,27.6,12.5,32.6,17.3  c22.3,21.1,22.8,51.6,23,61.4c0.2,9.5,0.7,37.9-19.2,61.4c-18.5,21.9-43.5,28.8-65.2,30.7c-31.6,2.7-51.9,2.2-69-1.9V394.5z   M570.6,908.5V701.4c33.3-3.2,60.9-2.9,80.5-1.9c39.3,2,59.3,3.2,80.5,15.3c7,4,29.8,17.4,44.1,46c5.2,10.5,15.6,35.6,9.6,67.1  c-2.2,11.7-9.7,39.6-34.5,59.5c-11,8.7-25.4,16-63.3,21.1C660.3,912.2,620.2,914.9,570.6,908.5z M1835.5,1052.5  c218.7,0,395-184.3,395-403s-177.3-407-396-407s-396,188.3-396,407S1616.8,1052.5,1835.5,1052.5z M1835,390.5  c131.3,0,237.8,116.2,237.8,259.5S1966.3,909.5,1835,909.5S1597.2,793.3,1597.2,650S1703.7,390.5,1835,390.5z M636.5,1879.5v1l1,129  v0.1c73,0.1,142.9,0.3,216,0.4c-5.4,14.1-15,34.1-31.6,54.7c-5.9,7.2-35.7,43.1-89.4,63.7c-58.3,22.4-109.4,13.3-136.9,8.1  c-54.1-10.3-90.3-33.6-98.9-39.3c-39-25.9-60.5-55.8-71.8-71.8c-14.1-20-35.1-50.4-44.7-96.2c-2.4-11.6-10.4-54.2,2.7-107.1  c3.5-14.3,14.4-52.5,44.7-92.2c9.3-12.2,39.6-49.6,93.5-75.9c15.2-7.4,47.4-21.4,90.8-25.7c7.7-0.8,40-3.7,81.3,4.1  c19.2,3.6,46.7,9,77.2,25.7c14.7,8,31,19.8,63.7,43.4c8.8,6.3,15.7,12.5,20.5,16l90-106c-15.9-18.7-35.7-40.2-71-63  c-54-35-103.7-45.6-141.8-53.3c-31.3-6.3-86.6-17-158.1-6.3c-59.3,8.9-105.3,28.7-134.6,44.3c-49.5,26.2-82,56.1-95.8,69.6  c-39.5,38.6-60.6,75.2-65,83.1c-4.7,8.2-27.1,48.6-39.8,107.5c-2.3,10.9-9.1,44.7-9,89.4c0,22.3,0.4,59.9,13.6,106.6  c10.1,35.8,23.2,61,32.5,78.6c11,20.9,29,54.4,62.3,90.3c39,42.1,79.9,66.8,106.6,80.4c46.4,23.6,85.8,31.6,109.3,36.1  c25.3,4.9,72.3,11.8,131,6.3c27.9-2.6,61.2-6,102.1-21.7c14.8-5.7,58.3-23.6,103-63.2c42.8-37.9,65.1-76.5,79.5-102.1  c12.4-21.9,31.2-55.8,42.5-104.8c10.8-46.8,9.9-87,7.3-113.9L636.5,1879.5z M1019,1874.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9l1.4,0L1019,1874.6z   M1753.3,1919.6l291.8,1.1v-1.1l-1.1-142.2l-285.5,1.1h-1.1l1-137.9h1l304.6-3.3h1.1v-151.7h-464.6v2.1l-0.5,794l0,0.4h470.4v-146.4  h-317.1V1919.6z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: You'd need to use SMIL or javascript rather than CSS animations in order to support those browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've read somewhere that chrome deprecated SMIL. Does that mean that I'm making something that at some point won't work on Chrome?

Comment: They did, then they changed their mind and cancelled the deprecation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying geometric attributes, such as `width`, is a new thing in SVG 2.  Only Chrome has implemented that so far.

You will need to use a different method to animate your `<rect>`.  For example, you could move it horizontally using a `transform`, instead of changing its width.

**Update**

<strike>It looks like there is a bug in Firefox at the moment, causing CSS selectors to not match elements in the `<defs>` section.</strike>

The solution is to use the logo as the clippath, and move a blue rectangle in and out instead.

```css
svg#bogeLogo {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#bogePath {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 8;
}

svg#bogeLogo #bogeFinal {
  fill: blue;
  transition: all 1.4s ease-out !important;
  transform: translateX(-2552px);
}

svg#bogeLogo:hover #bogeFinal {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="bogeLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2551.2 2551.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <path id="bogePath" d="M1263.5,1239.5l0-1l0.8-1194.9l-60.3,0l-0.6,1195.9l-1146.6,0.2v60.3l1146.6-0.5v1195h59l1-1195  l1231.9,0.5l0-60.3L1263.5,1239.5z M779.6,1037c98.3-37.9,134.5-130.5,138.1-140c6.8-18.3,31.3-87,1.9-161.1  c-20.6-52-58.4-82.8-74.8-95.9c-23.2-18.5-45.4-27.8-61.3-34.5c13.2-6.5,52.6-26.9,76.7-90.2c26-68.5-0.8-128.3-7.7-143.8  c-25.5-57.3-74.1-84.5-95-96.9c-31.8-19-83.7-25.5-104.2-26.3L410.2,248v3.2l-1.1,800.3v1.1l293.7-0.2  C721.3,1051.7,748.9,1048.8,779.6,1037z M570.6,394.5c46.8-9.2,80.5-1.6,97.8,3.8c19.2,6.1,27.6,12.5,32.6,17.3  c22.3,21.1,22.8,51.6,23,61.4c0.2,9.5,0.7,37.9-19.2,61.4c-18.5,21.9-43.5,28.8-65.2,30.7c-31.6,2.7-51.9,2.2-69-1.9V394.5z   M570.6,908.5V701.4c33.3-3.2,60.9-2.9,80.5-1.9c39.3,2,59.3,3.2,80.5,15.3c7,4,29.8,17.4,44.1,46c5.2,10.5,15.6,35.6,9.6,67.1  c-2.2,11.7-9.7,39.6-34.5,59.5c-11,8.7-25.4,16-63.3,21.1C660.3,912.2,620.2,914.9,570.6,908.5z M1835.5,1052.5  c218.7,0,395-184.3,395-403s-177.3-407-396-407s-396,188.3-396,407S1616.8,1052.5,1835.5,1052.5z M1835,390.5  c131.3,0,237.8,116.2,237.8,259.5S1966.3,909.5,1835,909.5S1597.2,793.3,1597.2,650S1703.7,390.5,1835,390.5z M636.5,1879.5v1l1,129  v0.1c73,0.1,142.9,0.3,216,0.4c-5.4,14.1-15,34.1-31.6,54.7c-5.9,7.2-35.7,43.1-89.4,63.7c-58.3,22.4-109.4,13.3-136.9,8.1  c-54.1-10.3-90.3-33.6-98.9-39.3c-39-25.9-60.5-55.8-71.8-71.8c-14.1-20-35.1-50.4-44.7-96.2c-2.4-11.6-10.4-54.2,2.7-107.1  c3.5-14.3,14.4-52.5,44.7-92.2c9.3-12.2,39.6-49.6,93.5-75.9c15.2-7.4,47.4-21.4,90.8-25.7c7.7-0.8,40-3.7,81.3,4.1  c19.2,3.6,46.7,9,77.2,25.7c14.7,8,31,19.8,63.7,43.4c8.8,6.3,15.7,12.5,20.5,16l90-106c-15.9-18.7-35.7-40.2-71-63  c-54-35-103.7-45.6-141.8-53.3c-31.3-6.3-86.6-17-158.1-6.3c-59.3,8.9-105.3,28.7-134.6,44.3c-49.5,26.2-82,56.1-95.8,69.6  c-39.5,38.6-60.6,75.2-65,83.1c-4.7,8.2-27.1,48.6-39.8,107.5c-2.3,10.9-9.1,44.7-9,89.4c0,22.3,0.4,59.9,13.6,106.6  c10.1,35.8,23.2,61,32.5,78.6c11,20.9,29,54.4,62.3,90.3c39,42.1,79.9,66.8,106.6,80.4c46.4,23.6,85.8,31.6,109.3,36.1  c25.3,4.9,72.3,11.8,131,6.3c27.9-2.6,61.2-6,102.1-21.7c14.8-5.7,58.3-23.6,103-63.2c42.8-37.9,65.1-76.5,79.5-102.1  c12.4-21.9,31.2-55.8,42.5-104.8c10.8-46.8,9.9-87,7.3-113.9L636.5,1879.5z M1019,1874.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9l1.4,0L1019,1874.6z   M1753.3,1919.6l291.8,1.1v-1.1l-1.1-142.2l-285.5,1.1h-1.1l1-137.9h1l304.6-3.3h1.1v-151.7h-464.6v2.1l-0.5,794l0,0.4h470.4v-146.4  h-317.1V1919.6z"/>
    <clipPath id="bogeClip">
      <use xlink:href="#bogePath"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#bogePath"/>
  <g clip-path="url(#bogeClip)">
    <rect id="bogeFinal" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in Firefox at the moment where CSS selectors won't match elements in defs section if the selector also reverences the svg. So `#bogeClip rect {}` works, but `#bogeLogo #bogeClip rect {}` doesn't.

Comment: For reference, I have reported the Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434642

Comment: No bug in Firefox here.